# Gemalto SmartCard Get status issue

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform

> I’m programming an applet for a Java Card. During this process, I’ve encountered a unique byte sequence that I’m having difficulty comprehending. According to the documentation, it’s related to the ‘Get Status’ command and its parameters. The sequence is A>> T=0 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A-size 4F00 DB...E3 00. Can anyone help me understand how to calculate or interpret this particular byte sequence? Response AID Returned,

> A>> T=0 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A-size 4F00-const DBEE847A13CF3EE3-random_byte  00
> A<< (0019+2) (24ms) E3114F08 A000000018434D00-aid 9F700101C5019E 9000

its always random "DBEE847A13CF3EE3" when write cap by gp.exe console.

Comment: The question is not clear. Encountered is vague. The response your are giving is not an apdu response.